# How to Display a Default Image in ImageView Of RecyclerView's Item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-camera

In my Android App, the Captured image along with its details is stored and displayed in a recycler View. The Details are name and description of the picture. I'm storing the details along with Storage path(mCurrentpath) of the captured image in a room database table. I'm able to retrieve each row of the database and display it in recyclerview item. The problem is - if I try to save only the details without any picture captured,the item displays an empty imageview along with details. Instead of displaying empty image view i need to display an default image.Kindly help
Note: i also tried to save a default string in database if image not captured. and checked With if() statement in onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageHolder imageHolder, int i) {
        ImageEntry currentImageEntry = imageEntries.get(i);
        String storedAddress = currentImageEntry.getImageStoredAddress();

          if(storedAddress != "Address is null") {
            imageHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImageEntry.getImageStoredAddress()));
        }else {imageHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);}


        imageHolder.textViewTpye.setText(currentImageEntry.getPropertyType());
        imageHolder.textViewDesc.setText(currentImageEntry.getProprtyDescription());
    }
```

thanks

Comment: "Address is null" is the text you are using if there is no image path? i mean with that you check if there is image or not?

Comment: Can’t you just set the default image directly in the xml file and just change it if the adress is not null?

Comment: if no image is captured, " Address is null" is stored as Image address in database. again im checking that in on bindViewholder

Comment: the if - else Statement inside OnBindViewHolder is not working as i expect.the If {} shows the desired result but  the else part is not displaying the default image , instead the image view is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: that was an eye opener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `equals` for comapring string value

```
if (storedAddress.equals("Address is null")) { 
    imageHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
} else {
    imageHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImageEntry.getImageStoredAddress()));
}
```

**Note :** `==` tests object references, `.equals()` tests the string values.

for Example,

```
String a="test me";
String b="test me";

a == b //this will return false

a.equals(b) //this will return true
```

Comment: It works Perfectly , Thank you very much to you and all

Comment: glad to help. please accept answer if you feel it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Place a default image in XML file and change this image 
**if**

```
if(storedAddress != "Address is null")
```

**or If no  image is captured , store default image address in database.**